# Conditional Formatting on a value in a range A:C which is closest to an input value y

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, gs-conditional-formatting

I'm working on a spreadsheet which calculates my caloric intake. The sheet comprises two parts. One which is simple data which I input such as weight and calorie intake. And a second table showing the number of calories per pound required to either lose, maintain or gain.

[image]

What should my formula be under conditional formatting in order to highlight the value in list closes to 1500?

Comment: Is there an equal increment between calorie values

Comment: @TomSharpe, nope. but the question has been answered. :)

Comment: Yes that's a good general answer - but if they had been equal increments (they look _very_ similar) you could have used simple division. In fact it would have been a linear relationship and you could get an exact answer - not limited by the values in the list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
=IF($C4=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(SORT(ARRAYFORMULA({$C$4:$C, ABS($C$4:$C-$F$4)}), 2, 1), 1, 1), 1)
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Well, I'm amazed. Done. Thank you!